# Getting TFS to pull out comment tokens

Tags: tfs

I've worked with Jenkins in the past, and there was a plugin that would pull out comment tokens (TODO, REVIEW, HACK etc) from C# code and display it in the build summaries (kinda like code warnings).

I can't seem to find anything similar for TFS. Is this available anywhere, either out of the box or as an add-in?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin, but the Code Analysis tool picks up things like "TODO" you could [write a custom rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380660.aspx) for the others and then get TFS to run that as part of the build.

Hopefully you're [running code analysis](http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2013/01/20/tfs-build-running-static-code-analysis-for-specific-configuration.aspx) anyway so it would just add extra warnings